# Angular2 testing data in decorators

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have a component and I want to check the selector in unit tests

```
@Component({
     selector: 'my-component',
)}
```

I want to test like this

```
describe('My Component', function(){ 
   it('should have a selector', function() {
      expect( ___ ).toBe('my-component');
   }); 
)}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In you need to use **Reflect Metadata** to have access to these hints. Supposing that the class of the component is `MyComponent`, you could do this to test the selector:

```
describe('My Component', function(){ 
  it('should have a selector', function() {
    var annotations = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', MyComponent);
    // Supposing the first annotations is of type ComponentMetadata
    expect(annotations[0].selector).toBe('my-component');
  });
});
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/HQc1qt?p=preview.

Comment: I didn't know how to test `decorator's selector metadata`. Thanks for indicating the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

On rc you may need to retrieve the rereflactor from core then use the reflector.annotations to retrieve the info

```
import {reflector} from '@angular/core/src/reflection/reflection';

it('should have a selector', inject([SettingsComponent], (component: any) => {
    let meta = reflector.annotations(SettingsComponent)[0];
    expect(meta.selector).toBe('Settings');
}));
```